# Verify Paypal id is valid or not inserted by user

Tags: paypal, payment, verification

I want to verify that whether user has entered valid Paypal id or not. If not than user can't do registration. I've also visited this [1]: [How can I verify a PayPal ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478678/how-can-i-verify-a-paypal-id) question but it doesn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't find a direct answer because "valid PayPal ID" doesn't have a single fixed meaning. You will need to be more specific as to what you are trying to discover. Then there may or may not be a way to accomplish what you want, since PayPal protects some aspects of their customers' account and identity information for their protection (and for business reasons).

A bit of background that may help you clarify your question, if not necessarily answer it:

Any email (or phone number) can be configured to receive PayPal payments, in many cases even if the email was not attached to a PayPal account at the time the payment was sent. However, not all PayPal products can function in this way (e.g. you cannot make API calls as an account that has not been set up and has not generated API credentials). Are you asking about receiving money, and if so with which product(s)?

Most people can pay through PayPal if sent to a PayPal page, whether they are accountholders or not (depending upon the PayPal product being used). In addition to guest payments and/or direct credit card payments through PayPal, people can set up PayPal accounts when they arrive and immediately pay with them. So collecting email first and refusing to go forward if there is no PayPal account attached to that email would loose you potential customers. It would also "let through" many customers who could not pay, such as people who know an email address but don't own the attached PayPal account. PayPal also intentionally declines to easily answer questions about whether an email has an associated PayPal account in order to make it harder for bad actors to accumulate lists of PayPal accounts (often with associated personal information) for spear phishing campaigns. There are some APIs that allow you to get limited information about a PayPal account but there are limits associated with these APIs; see e.g. GetVerifiedStatus documentation at:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

Note also that Verified has a particular technical meaning in PayPal, and is NOT AT ALL THE SAME as "able to pay you."

If you want to know if someone can log into their PayPal account, and then use that PayPal account to get information about the user (as well as potentially pay you), that's easy: use Login with PayPal. That's what it's for. Naturally this requires the user to login and assent to your use of their information.

If you want to know if someone can take a particular action (e.g. make a payment), at this moment, the only way to be certain is to actionally request that action. You have options short of actually requesting money; if you want to ensure the user has funds and reserve them for you to collect shortly you can request an authorization rather than a sale. If you want to make sure the user can log in, has payment mechanisms and generally looks ready to pay you (but WITHOUT reserving and guaranteeing funds) you can request an Order.

Hopefully one of these things is what you are asking for?

If you have a PayPal AccountID (a PayPal-generated ID rather than an externally-generated identifier like email or phone number) you can pass it to certain APIs (such as the GetVerifiedStatus), so many of the same options above apply.